# How to add a button "Add More" with ajax for adding multiple fields?

Tags: 7, forms, hooks, ajax

I want to add a button "Add More" with ajax for adding multiple fields
I have writed this code, I don't understand why when I click to "add more" nothing work, there is an solution?

this is my code:

```
function produits_add($form, &$form_submit){

        if(!isset($form_state['num_names'])){
            $form_state['num_names']=1;
        }

        // Create wrapper for ajax
        $form['#prefix'] = '<div id="form-wrapper">';
        $form['#suffix'] = '</div>';

        for ($i = 0; $i < $form_state['num_names']; $i++) {

            $form['name_' . $i] = array(
                '#type' => 'textfield',
                '#title' => t('Name')

            );
        }

        $form['add_button']= array(
            '#type' => 'button',
            '#value'=> 'Add more',
            '#ajax' => array(
                'callback' => 'ajax_add_col',
                'method' => 'replace',
                'effect' => 'fade',
                'wrapper' => 'form-wrapper',
            ),
        );




        $form['submit'] = array(
            '#type' => 'submit',
            '#value' => 'Submit',
            '#submit' => array('produits_add_submit'),
        );





        return $form;
    }

    function ajax_add_col($form, &$form_state){

        $form_state['num_names']++;

        // rebuild whole form with new values
        $form_state['rebuild'] = true;
    }

function produits_add_submit($form, &$form_state){

// Some code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your form function, group the textfields under a key, you can define your own key. I use `group` here.

```php
// Create wrapper for ajax
$form['group']['#prefix'] = '<div id="form-wrapper">';
$form['group']['#suffix'] = '</div>';

for ($i = 0; $i < $form_state['num_names']; $i++) {

  $form['group']['name_' . $i] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('Name')
  );
}
```

In your ajax callback, return part of the form.

```php
function ajax_add_col($form, &$form_state){

  $form_state['num_names']++;

  // rebuild whole form with new values
  $form_state['rebuild'] = true;

  return $form['group'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still having this problem, like above please change your button type to submit.

 `$form['add_button']= array(
            '#type' => 'button',
            '#value'=> 'Add more',
            '#ajax' => array(
                'callback' => 'ajax_add_col',
                'method' => 'replace',
                'effect' => 'fade',
                'wrapper' => 'form-wrapper',
            ),
        );`

---

## Change to

`$form['add_button']= array(
     '#type' => 'submit', //change this submit
     '#value'=> 'Add more',
     '#submit' => array('ajax_example_add_more_add_one'),//add this to handle 
                                            //your increment and rebuild form 
     '#ajax' => array(
        'callback' => 'ajax_add_col',
         'wrapper' => 'form-wrapper',//returns the fieldset
         ),
     );`